# Google map API theme option page not displaying

Tags: function, javascript

I'm having some issues with the integration of a google map in my web site which can geocode an address before displaying the map with the correct location.

So i have a script (it worked when i was in localhost but since i put the web site online nothing happens) :

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
                <script>
                var geocoder;
                var map;
                var firstLoc;

                function findAddress() {
                  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                  geocoder.geocode( { 'address' : document.getElementById('address_field').value}, 
                    function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        firstLoc = results[0].geometry.location;
                        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-location"),
                        {
                            center: firstLoc,
                            zoom: 17,
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                        });

                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                          map: map,
                          position: results[0].geometry.location
                        });
                    } 
                    else {
                      alert('Geocode failed: ' + status);
                    }
                }
                  );
                }
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', findAddress); 
                </script>
```

I put an address in a field in my theme option page then i register the value and put it in a hidden input in my front-end and try to get it with `geocoder.geocode( { 'address' : document.getElementById('address_field').value}`

Seems to have a problem with geocoding, i tested with a simple script with a fix position and it showed fine.

In case you need it this is how i display the map in the front-end :

```
            <div class="contact-map">
                <div id="map-location"></div>
                <form class="address-hidden">
                  <?php echo "<input id='address_field' type='text' value= '{$content_options['geolocal_setting']}'/>"?>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: Check your api access, you may need to whitelist it for all domains or for the specific live domain.

Comment: This is the key access thing i have to set in the link `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>` right ? Anyway like i said i'm able to display a simple map without geocode

Comment: You manage what domains you can access the api with here: https://code.google.com/apis/console

Comment: It was already activate

Comment: put {$content_options['geolocal_setting']} in double quotes and also check if there is any error in browser's console. Use f12 on browser for the same.

Comment: The value is saved and display in my hidden address field i have no problem with this but i can't geocode it ! The exact same code works perfectly in another theme option page and display the map with the address i wrote in the back-end. This is why i don't understand..

Comment: Mmmmh it's weird, i only replaced `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', findAddress);`  by `window.onload=findAddress;` and it works, if you know why i'd like to know ^^